# GIT - cannot squash commits : fatal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I'm trying to squash my last 2 commits with git.
In this example I have created a branch from another branch called develop and I have 3 new commits, this is the git log :

```
commit a350cf6071db1bcaa2a37710a61508565a34d917
Author: tibbus
Date:   Tue Sep 6 11:49:19 2016 +0200

    commit message #3

commit 8c0384b995831e5a62b423721434005788b2eb63
Author: tibbus
Date:   Tue Sep 6 11:49:01 2016 +0200

    commit message #2

commit 6eab9df2df71196d62dab3c6caed9cd0ac6aeee5
Author: tibbus
Date:   Tue Sep 6 11:48:41 2016 +0200

    commit message #1
...
more commits from develop...
```

So I want to squash commit #3 and commit #2 into one single commit, I try :

```
git rebase -i HEAD˜2
```

and I get this error :

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD˜2
```

If I do :

```
git rebase -i develop
```

Works fine, but I do not want to squash all 3 commits, I want only the latest 2. I have read that this error appears when you don't have enough commits, but I definitely have ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Will you please post the output of "`git log --oneline --graph --decorate`"?

Comment: Hi @Leon , thanks for for your interest. I have saved that command log into a jsfiddle to be more easy to read : https://jsfiddle.net/083kvr6b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong `~` symbol. ˜ in your command is [the small tilde](http://unicodelookup.com/#˜/1) non-ASCII character, whereas you need the regular [tilde](http://unicodelookup.com/#~/1) ASCII symbol. Did you copy it from somewhere or the `~` on your keyboard inserts `˜`?

Copy&paste the command from my answer and it should work without any problem:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `tilda` (`~`). Seems to be a different ASCII and hence git command line is asking for a revision.